# Computer Loses connection to router

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, connection

I have a new Windows 8 Dell XPS desktop computer at work.  It has a Dell Wireless 1703 802.11 b/g/n (2.4ghz) wireless adapter.

Sporadically throughout the day I lose internet connectivity.  When I click on the wireless system tray icon, my company's router does not appear in the list.

No other computer on the network is losing connection, only this one.

I don't even know what to check.  Could it be an ip conflict that causes me to get booted off? (I use DHCP), but why wouldn't my computer be able to see the network.  The next time it happens I will see what happens when I try to access the router directly.

Comment: Have you contacted your company IT department?  There are many possible causes and the IT folks may need to do a site survey to see if there is an issue or the AP may provide info from a log.  Basically, IT should be your first call.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is either on their side (IT) or yours. Likely it is on your side.

Do other devices close to your area exhibit similar problems? Laptops? Smart phones?  etc...

First, I recommend looking for a driver update to the dell wireless adapter.

Also, if you can, I recommend obtaining a second wireless adapter, perhaps a USB adapter (easy to plug in) that you can use to rule out several of the items listed below.

**Things to verify on your side:**

Bad Wireless signal

- Your antenna is under/behind some crazy desk that interferes with wireless signal
- Your desk is in an area where the building walls interferes with wireless signal
- There are a lot of other wireless clients in your area (saturation)

Bad Wireless adapter

- Faulty hardware - somehow the wireless hardware is damaged
- Incorrect driver installed
- Bug in the Dell Windows 8 drivers
- Bug in Windows 8

**Things to verify on their (IT department) side:**

- You probably won't have the ability to verify anything on their end. Just call them and tell them what you have tried and I'm guessing they will figure it out.